# Unicode and html emtities

Tags: html, unicode, ascii

I have a site with charset=utf-8 and running Bootstrap 3.7 with html5 doctype.

It seems that when someone inserts this:

```
<div>&#139;text&#155;</div>
```

it renders in a wrong way - like this:

```
?tekst?
```

It works if we use:

```
<div>&#8249;text&#8250;</div>
```

or

```
<div>&lsaquo;text&rsaquo;</div>
```

which gives us: `‹text›`
but I would like to know why the first set of unicode font doesn't work?

Comment: What characters are `&#139;` and `&#155;` supposed to be?

Comment: What are your expectation? `&@139;` is a control character in Unicode. And because all web is now Unicode, just use a Unicode editor and put real character there. In short: entities with numbers are encoding dependent, so very easy to broke (especially on upgrade), so try not to use them

Comment: Sorry, some quotation marks: `‹text›`

Comment: Thank you, Giacomo. I know I shouldn't use them. I'm just looking for an explanation why.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi your assertion that "_entities with numbers are encoding dependent_" was valid in **obsolete implementations** of HTML only (maybe early MSIE?). Nowadays, we are in the 3rd millennium, time of Unicode ubiquity, I hope. Use codepoints from https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt ad libitum, easy in _hexadecimal_ variants of numeric entity reference e.g. `&#x2039;text&#x203A;` for `‹text›`…

Comment: @JosefZ, thank you so much for your comment - could you make it an answer instead, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in [this *W3C Recommendation*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) (supported in HTLM as well):

[Character and Entity References](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references)

> [Definition: A character reference refers to a specific character in
> the ISO/IEC 10646 character set, for example one not directly
> accessible from available input devices.]
>
> Character Reference
>
> ```
> CharRef ::= '&#' [0-9]+ ';' | '&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ';'
> ```
>
> Well-formedness constraint: Legal Character. Characters referred to
> using character references must match the production for [Char](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)
> (***any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and
> FFFF**.*).
>
> If the character reference begins with " `&#x` ", the digits and
> letters up to the terminating `;` provide a *hexadecimal*
> representation of the character's code point in [ISO/IEC
> 10646](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c076835_ISO_IEC_10646_2020(E).zip).
> If it begins just with " `&#` ", the digits up to the
> terminating `;` provide a *decimal* representation of the character's
> code point.

**Important**: [character codes … are synchronized between Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646](https://www.unicode.org/faq/unicode_iso.html)